# Почему блок, плавающий вправо, смещается вниз вместе с блоком, плавающим влево?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, вёрстка

Надо, чтобы синий блок плавал вправо вверху контейнера `#wrapper`, а не уходил вниз вместе со вторым красным блоком.

Вопросы:

1. Почему синий блок уходит вниз вместе с красным блоком?
2. Как сделать так, чтобы синий блок плавал вправо вверху контейнера?

```css
#wrapper {
  color: #fff;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #000;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: darkblue;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div>
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="left"></div>

  </div>
  <div class="right"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Дополнил и подкорректировал вопрос

Comment: Почему id одинаковые?

Comment: @Qwertiy щас исправим)

Comment: @Qwertiy исправил

Comment: Я уточнил 2-ой вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавил div'у с clearfix'ом обводку. Никакой float после него не может оказаться выше, поскольку этот блок уже отрисован.

```css
#wrapper {
  color: #fff;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #000;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: darkblue;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div style="outline:4px solid green">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="left"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

И тут дело именно в отрисованности, а не в `clear` - ты же не ожидаешь, что в следующем примере синий блок будет поверх серого?

```html
<div style="background: silver; height: 2em;"></div>
<div style="float: right; background: blue; height: 3em; width: 3em;"></div>
```

Исправить можно переставив синий блок в начало разметки:

```css
#wrapper {
  color: #fff;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #000;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: darkblue;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="right"></div>
  <div>
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="left"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```